# Catching signals

Tags: c

I'm trying to write this little game. What I want is that when the time is over the program prints "off time" and then it ends. Why does it prints and not end?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
void gestore(int segnale);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int random, answer;
    srand(getpid());
    random = rand () % atoi(argv[1])+1;
    printf("Write a number: ");
    alarm(3);
    if(signal(SIGALRM, gestore))
        return 0;
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    while(answer != random){
        if(answer > random)
            printf("higher\n");
        else if(answer < random)
            printf("lower\n");
        printf("Write a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
    }
    printf("guessed\n");
}
void gestore(int segnale){
    signal(segnale, SIG_IGN);
    printf("off time!");
    signal(segnale, gestore);
}
```

Comment: What does `excve` have to do with it?  And if the program does not end then it certainly does not crash with a segmentation fault.

Comment: My fault sorry. Edited.

Comment: After your SIGALARM is handled and the handler returns, control will resume in the function that was executing when the signal was received.  That function might continue as if nothing had happened, or it might fail, depending on a variety of factors, but it won't automatically exit the program.  If you want the program to end when it receives the `SIGALARM`, then why not have the handler call `exit()`?

Comment: I was thinking to use kill(getpid(), SIGTERM). Could I use it? Or I must use   exit()?

Comment: Undefined behavior for calling a non async-safe function in a signal handler context.

Comment: It would be silly to use `kill()` when you could use `raise()`, instead, to send a `SIGTERM` to yourself.  And you could do so, but that seems very roundabout.  In my mind, `_exit()` (as opposed to `exit()`, which I first recommended but which is not async-signal safe) is the stylistically right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem!